# design pattern for "save"

Tags: c++, xml, qt, design-patterns, save

I'm currently working on a "save" mechanism, which allows a user to save the project his working on on hard disc. The output will be a XML file containing all kinds of data.
Now our project structure is about to change and we need to write a new xml file (create a new save method).
So now here comes the challenge: When saving I want the user to be able to choose which file format he will be creating (version1 (old) or version2 (new)).
Does anyone now how to achieve that? Is there a suitable design pattern around?
Remarks:
- The data we are saving can be seen as unrelated blocks, so it would actually be easy to exchange an old block with a new one.
- The whole goal of the thing is, it should be readable again when loading an old project. (I assume this can be done by tags, and just react on tags when loading?)

Comment: [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) sounds like what you want.

Comment: [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) Can be used to save an object to an xml format.

Comment: In some sense that's the same problem that Google Protocol Buffers and Facebook Thrift are trying to solve...

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a good application for the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

You would create an abstract base class `FileFormat` (the Strategy interface) with two virtual functions, `projectToXml` and `xmlToProject`, which are supposed to turn your internal project representation into XML or vice versa.

Then you create two implementing subclasses `FileFormatNew` and `FileFormatLegacy` (these are the concrete strategies).

Your save functions would then additionally require an instance of FileFormat, and call the corresponding method of that object to do the data conversion. Your load function could choose the strategy to use by examining the XML tree for something which tells it which version it is.

And when you ever need to support another file format, you just have to create a new class which is a subclass of FileFormat.

**Addendum after the exchange in the comments**

When you are going to have a lot of versions with very small differences and you still want to use the Strategy pattern, you could make the FileFormat a composite of multiple strategies: A CircleStragegy, a RectangleStrategy, a LineStrategy etc.. In that case I wouldn't use different classes for different versions of the FileFormat. I would create a static factory function for each version which returns a FileFormat with the Strategy objects used in that version.

```
FileFormat FileFormat::createVersion1_0() {
    return new FileFormat(
        new LineStrategyOld(),
        new CircleStrategyOld(),
        new RectangleStragegyOld()
    );
}

FileFormat FileFormat::createVersion1_1() {
    // the 1.1 version introduced the new way to save lines
    return new FileFormat(            
        new LineStrategyNew(),
        new CircleStrategyOld(),
        new RectangleStragegyOld()
    );
}

FileFormat FileFormat::createVersion1_2() {
    // 1.2 uses the new format to save circles
    return new FileFormat(            
        new LineStrategyNew(),
        new CircleStrategyNew(),
        new RectangleStragegyOld()
    );
}

FileFormat FileFormat::createVersion1_3() {
    // 1.3 uses a new format to save rectangles, but we realized that
    // the new way to save lines wasn't that good after all, so we
    // returned to the old way.
    return new FileFormat(            
        new LineStrategyOld(),
        new CircleStrategyNew(),
        new RectangleStragegyNew()
    );
}
```

**Note:** In real code you would of course use more descriptive suffixes than "Old" and "New" for your strategy class names.

Comment: so basically each object is responsible for delivering the xml data? Meaning I would not have one large method collecting all using public getters and setters for different members, but instead i would call a method "getAppropriateData()" and i would get the data from the object itself?
And with this approach i would even for the tiniest changes between two save version need a new concrete strategy, which calls all the same functions as the last did, except for the one tiny change, right?

Comment: Redundant code should always be avoided. When two strategies are very similar and only differ in some small detail, either one could inherit from the other or you could move most of the code to common private functions of the base class, while doing only the parts which are truly different in each derived class.

Comment: Regarding how to gather the data which needs to be saved by your strategies: I would need to know how your data is structured to give any recommendation about that. When you want to avoid to expose too many details of your project class through having getters for everything which needs to be saved, you could use the Visitor pattern to gather the data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: first: thanks for all the great tipps! second the thing is the following:
Imagine I would be creating a drawing tool. Right now I write my save function in which I save rects (by saving the coords of all 4 corners) and circles (coords of the center and a radius), lets call that Version1. For the next release I changed my structure and would now like to save the rect by one corner and width and height - the rest stay. Thus Version2 could inherit from Version1.
Now I change the save of a circle, thus Version3 inherits from Version2 and everything starts to mess up...

Comment: When you are going to have a lot of versions with very small differences and you still want to use the Strategy pattern, you could make the FileFormat a composite of multiple strategies: A CircleStragegy, a RectangleStrategy, a LineStrategy etc.. In that case I wouldn't use different classes for different versions of the FileFormat. I would create a factory method for each version which returns a FileFormat with the Strategy objects needed for that version.

Comment: I made an addendum to my answer which gives an example for that.